# MongogoDB replica set on EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I set up the mongodb conf file with (the IPs are actual numeric IPs

```
bindIp: [127.0.0.1,external_Ip]
```

and

```
replication:
  replSetName: "rs0"
```

and did that on 2 other servers.

```
rs.addArb('ArbIP:27017')
```

executed no problem

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.add('54.183.186.123:27017')
2016-07-23T09:03:22.238+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error doing query: failed: network error while attempting to run command 'count' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'  :
DB.prototype.runCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:135:1
DB.prototype.runReadCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:112:16
DBQuery.prototype.count@src/mongo/shell/query.js:367:15
DBCollection.prototype.count@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1713:12
rs.add@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1143:1
@(shell):1:1

2016-07-23T09:03:22.239+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed
2016-07-23T09:03:22.240+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) ok
rs0:SECONDARY>
```

what went wrong and how do I solve it?
I don't know what other info you might need to help me so just ask.

Comment: You're using the public IPs.  Did you add each member's public IP to the security group?  Security group membership rules don't work when using the public IP, only the private IP, even if it's the public IP of the instance you're on.

Comment: What KarenB said, plus you should always use the private IP for communication between servers within your VPC, for security and performance.

Comment: right now I have the port 27017 to accept traffic from any ip.  I tried the private ip when I knew the public connected from the browser and was not able to connect.

Comment: @MarkB Some people might want to run multi-region replica sets, which would require public IP, but I agree, if the replica set is in one region, there's no reason to use the public IP.

Comment: @Daniel that's a terrible security risk.  Reconfigure each member to use the private IP and set up the security group to accept traffic from its own members on port 27017.  And delete the 0.0.0.0/0 rule.

Comment: @KarenB ok I have made that change but still get the same error that I listed